# Extra margin in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-percent-library, margin-left

I'm using **Support Android Percentage Library**'s RelativeLayout AKA **`android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout`** but **it has extra margin on the left edge same as `RelaytiveLayout` I didn't set any margin or padding but it's still has it**, Search a lot and done anything which worked for other people... but NOT SOLVED!

Activity Main Layout codes :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainAppbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainFlexibleSpace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp">
       <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/mainPercentRelativeLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/mainEnterLink"
               android:text="@string/str_mainMessageText"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Any Help? [See This Image of my rendered Layout Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn2UF.png)

Comment: As I see in your code why you are adding `2 time ToolBar` to your Layout ?

Comment: try to add marginleft  0 and refresh

Comment: Ironman The Example which i use done this, i did it too... i know that its not necessary... :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's a issue with the toolbar too (mainFlexibleSpace). If yes then,

Declare the toolBar in java and do this.
`toolBar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);`